# PHP variable not defined inside while loop

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable thats value is set at the start of my document but when I use my WHILE LOOP it get UNDEFINED and stops working.

Can anyone help how to keep this value assigned?

The variable I'm trying to keep defined is $lang

```
$lang = "en";// base url


function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_delivery WHERE user_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $phrase =   array(  
                            'de'    =>  'Bearbeiten',
                            'en'    =>  'Edit',
                            'es'    =>  'Editar',
                            'fr'    =>  'Éditer',
                            'it'    =>  'Modifica');
                        echo $phrase[$lang];
    }   
}
```

Comment: More correctly, your variable is not available in the function scope (PHP doesn't have a separate scope for while loops). Globals are not available unless you use the `global` keyword within a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside a function you need to use global. first line in function

```
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
    global $lang;

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_delivery WHERE user_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $phrase =   array(  
                            'de'    =>  'Bearbeiten',
                            'en'    =>  'Edit',
                            'es'    =>  'Editar',
                            'fr'    =>  'Éditer',
                            'it'    =>  'Modifica');
                        echo $phrase[$lang];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$lang` is outside the scope of `getAccountDeliveryDetails()`. Unlike in JavaScript/Java/AS (which you may be coming from), a variable defined outside a function does not automatically come up in the scope of the function.

Assuming `$lang` is free-standing/global, you can call `global $lang;` as the first line of your function in order to import the variable. However, that's not a good solution on the long-term front.

Comment: What would you suggest be a better solution for this case? I would think one variable containing the languages is a proper solution. Passing the language to every function as a param where you need it seems a lot harder to maintain.

Comment: In his case, considering that it'll affect every part of the site, I'd go down the `define()` route. `define('SITE_LANGUAGE','en')` in his config, and he can then use SITE_LANGUAGE anywhere he likes (and avoids polluting the global namespace while doing so).

Comment: and what if you can switch to nl?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from calling the initial `define()` with an environment variable as parameter.

Comment: Ah you're right. Not sure why, but I was under the impression that you couldnt define a constant with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use global for access external variable on a function

```
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
global $lang;
$query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_delivery WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$phrase =   array(  
                        'de'    =>  'Bearbeiten',
                        'en'    =>  'Edit',
                        'es'    =>  'Editar',
                        'fr'    =>  'Éditer',
                        'it'    =>  'Modifica');
                    echo $phrase[$lang];
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check [article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) about variable scope

```
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
   global $lang;
   ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$GLOBALS` to access your global variable, so replace your following line:

```
echo $phrase[$lang];
```

for this one:

```
echo $phrase[$GLOBALS['lang']];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare

```
global $lang
```

inside your function.

But it's definitely not a good programming practice.

See [PHP Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)  manual entry

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to do this:

**Globals**

Stay away from this way if you can since it creates a dependency on the super global existing in order for your code to work.

```
$lang = "en";// base url
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
    global $lang; //extra vars can be added after a , eg global $a, $b, $c;
    ....
}
```

**Super Globals**

Same problem as globals, however, this is even messier as it uses an existing super global and creates a sort of invisible dependency in that there is no need to use `global $varname`. Also, PHP coders will not expect you to save your custom variables in the existing super globals eg:

DO NOT DO THIS

```
$_SERVER['my_vars']['lang'] = "eg";// base url
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id){
    print $_SERVER['my_vars']['lang']; //ewwwww
    ....
}
```

**Function Parameters**

This is the usual and BEST way to pass parameters.

```
$lang = "en";// base url
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id, $lang){
    print $lang;
    ....
}
```

**Use (Closures)**

Doesn't really apply to your existing function (but closures are still considered functions), but here just to be that little more "complete" of an answer. You can pass them as parameters or use the "use" keyword to bring them in from their local scope.

```
$lang = "en";// base url
function ($id) use ($lang) {
    print $lang;
    ....
}
```

**Conclusion**

Go with the parameter option is possible. You can always use a DEFAULT value to prevent breaking any existing code eg:

```
function getAccountDeliveryDetails($id, $lang = 'eg'){

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_delivery WHERE user_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $phrase =   array(  
                            'de'    =>  'Bearbeiten',
                            'en'    =>  'Edit',
                            'es'    =>  'Editar',
                            'fr'    =>  'Éditer',
                            'it'    =>  'Modifica');
                        echo $phrase[$lang];
    }   
}
```

So you can call this function like this and the $lang will default to "en":

```
getAccountDeliveryDetails(23);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write  `global $lang;` inside `getAccountDeliveryDetails()` function

Reason:

Within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope. For example:

```
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 


    function test()
    { 
        echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
    } 

    test();
```

This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope. You may notice that this is a little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C are automatically available to functions unless specifically overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that people may inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

The global keyword

First, an example use of global:

Example #1 Using global

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

    function Sum()
    {
        global $a, $b;

        $b = $a + $b;
    } 

    Sum();

echo $b;
```

The above script will output 3. By declaring `$a` and `$b` global within the function, all references to either variable will refer to the global version. There is no limit to the number of global variables that can be manipulated by a function.